# How do I disable the face2face plugin for Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, plugins

I have recently installed and tried to use face2face plugin for mail and I have tried to delete it, however the plugin still seems to be active and I don't know how to disable it.

http://www.chungwasoft.com/face2face/ is the link for the plugin.

I have deleted the plugin from the ~/Library/Mail/Bundles folder and it hasn't stopped the plugin.

I would really like to revert mail back to the way it was before this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OK I found a way to do it. The plugin isn't that bad just not to my tastes. If you have this same issue the best way to solve the problem is to disable all the options in the View menu option and then delete the plugin file found in the directory above.